# What call loadInBackground method, how to retrieve list with data

Tags: java, android

I've fetch data from one of free api. Data are saving in arrayList. And I use AsyncTaskLoader to fetch data on other thread. And everything is going well but I don't know how to retrieve arrayList with data on MainActivity class.

MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: START");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        loaderManager.initLoader(EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID, null, this);

    } else {

    }

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: END");

}


@Override
public Loader<List<News>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader: START");

    NewsLoader newsloader = new NewsLoader(this,URL);
    List<News> list = newsloader.getList();
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader: list: " + list);

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader: END");

    return newsloader;
}
```

NewsLoader.java:

```
public class NewsLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<News>> {

private static final String TAG = "NewsLoader";
public List<News> listOfNews;
private String mUrl;

public NewsLoader(Context context, String url) {
    super(context);
    mUrl=url;
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    forceLoad();
}

@Override
public List<News> loadInBackground() {
    Log.i(TAG, "loadInBackground: START");

    if(mUrl == null){
        return null;
    }

    listOfNews = QueryUtils.fetchDataFromPage(mUrl);

    Log.i(TAG, "loadInBackground: END");
    return listOfNews;
}
public List<News> getList(){
    return listOfNews;
}
```

}

I've got News and QueryUtils class too but in these class everything goes well and problem is how to get access to list from MainActivity class.

When I declare List outside methods, under class declaration and create list getters and when I try get list from MainActivity:

```
    NewsLoader newsloader = new NewsLoader(this,URL);
    List<News> list = newsloader.getList();
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader: list: " + list);
```

and then list is null, although in other class (NewsLoader) data were assigned to list before calling "getList".

Or just simple question will solve the problem: 
Where list from loadInBackground from NewsLoader.java is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some tests, I came out with this conclusion:
If a Loader already exists then this line `loaderManager.initLoader(EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID, null, this);` will jump to the following method `onLoadFinished(Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> data)` which you don't have. So, override that method in your MainActivity.
Something like this:

```
//declare your arraylist here
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){...}

@Override
public Loader<List<News>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {...}

@Override
onLoadFinished(Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> data){
//assign data to your arraylist
}
```